# Changing all images in a directory and its sub-directories using a single ImageMagick command?

Tags: bash, image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a directory with multi level sub-directories containing .jpg files that I want to change using ImageMagick.

To change a single file I do `convert image0.jpg -resize x1000 -quality 82 small_image0.jpg`

But how can I do the same but for all the jpgs in every directories, with a single command?

That is:

- Apply `-resize x1000 -quality 82` to every jpg in all of the directories.
- Every output file should be in the same directory as its input file but with `small_` prepended to the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `find` and `bash`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

path=("$@")

while IFS= read -ru9 -d '' pic; do
   dirname=$(dirname "$pic")
   basename=$(basename "$pic")
   printf 'Converting %s to %s\n' "$pic" "$dirname/small_$basename"
   convert "$pic" -resize x1000 -quality 82 "$dirname/small_$basename" || exit
done 9< <(find "${path[@]}" -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0)
```

Assuming you name your script `myscript`, execute it with the path to the pictures as the argument.

```sh
./myscript /path/to/pictures
```

- Change `/path/to/pictures` with the correct path/directory, or add more path/directory separated by a space e.g. `./myscript path1 path2 anotherpath morepath`
  instead of just one directory.